# How to request a web page which contains ajax function in document.ready and need to completed it?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, winforms

I have a controller in website which get documentId, generate Html base Database and finally generate PDF document.
These tasks perform by ajax function in View of my controller (in document.ready).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" id="docId" value="@ViewBag.DocId" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="~/Content/Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var docId = $("#docId").val();
        if (!docId === "") {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "/AccountDoc/DocumentHtmlReport",
                data: { 'docId': docId },
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (result) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: "/Helper/CreatePDFDoc",
                            data: { 'srcHtml': result, 'docId': docId },

                            success: function () {
                               
                            },
                            error: function () {
                            }
                        });
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

I test it in browser 
"http://beta.mysite.com/AccountDosc/GeneratePdfDoc?docId=67"
and worked properly.

Now I need to call this controller from a c# windows application. I use these code and it return 200 OK to me:

```
 var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create($"http://beta.mysite.com/AccountDosc/GeneratePdfDoc?docId=={docId}");
 var response = request.GetResponse();
 response.Close();
```

but Pdf file doesn't generate.
I think WebRequest do not wait to complete all ajax complete.
How can I manage this problem?
Thanks to all...

Comment: The WebRequest isn't going to execute any javascript...

Comment: You can use either of these options: *1)* Automate the task using a WebBrowser control *2)* Send a 'POST' request to 'yoursite.com/helper/createpdfdoc' and pass 'srcHtml' and 'docId' as parameters of post request.

Comment: Thank a lot Reza, actually my application is a automation application and prefer not use automation web browser, and using directly CreatePdfDoc need to generate HTML source of it which require to call another controller to pass to CreatePdfDoc.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your are calling the wrong controller,in your browser your are calling "http://beta.mysite.com/**AccountDosc**/GeneratePdfDoc?docId=67" and in your code "/**Helper**/CreatePDFDoc"

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this code change for insert in question. In real code calling controller is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

1. Call http://yoursite.com/AccountDosc/GeneratePdfDoc?docId=67 and get the response result. That should give you the content to generate the pdf from.
2. Call http://yoursite.com/Helper/CreatePDFDoc?docId=67&srcHtml=htmlContent to get your pdf generated on the server.

I think, there are better ways to do it, maybe a rest web api or a WFC service but if you have some constraints it could work. Basicaly you need to run the steps you programmed in the jQuery script on your page one by one on your windows app, because web request is not gonna run any javascript.

Comment: Thank you Karel, I try to use current code to generate PDF doc. In another project I use web api to generate PDF but in this case speed to delivery project has high priority.